# How to run ATmega328P-PU using 3.7v Lipo 600mAh?

Tags: current, voltage-regulator, atmega, lipo, quad-copter

I want to run bare [ATmega328P-PU](http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-8271-8-bit-AVR-Microcontroller-ATmega48A-48PA-88A-88PA-168A-168PA-328-328P_datasheet_Summary.pdf) using 3.7v 600mAh Lipo Battery. The Lipo is used to run Nano Quadcopter. The discharge rate is 20C.

My Question is:
1. Will connecting Lipo to my atmega directly fry up my chip?
2. Do I need any Voltage regulator?

Comment: What does the Atmega data sheet say about permissible supply voltages?

Comment: The voltage should be fine for your 328P, provided you lower your clock speed enough. But the motors in your QC might generate significant noise and/or voltage spikes that could trouble or even damage your micro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Page 2 of your [datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-8271-8-bit-AVR-Microcontroller-ATmega48A-48PA-88A-88PA-168A-168PA-328-328P_datasheet_Summary.pdf):

```
Operating Voltage:
 1.8 - 5.5V
```

So yes you can connect it directly without a voltage regulator

Comment: And if you do decide to connect it directly, be sure to add some bulk capacitance, along with standard decoupling.

Comment: Will current provided by lipo fry up my atmega?

Comment: Well no, the current will depends on the needs of the atmega

Comment: I don't know why but my one atmega chip is not working now, because I provided about 1.8 A current once, voltage was 5.1V

Comment: Well from my little knowledge, the current of a atmega is only a couple of mA, if you got to Amps, maybe you miss wired something ...

Comment: What else is connected to your mega ? Robot ? motor? This could be the reason ...

Comment: Will the change in voltage as the battery is discharged make the internal clock inaccurate?

Comment: If you quote the voltage from the datasheet, also quote that it's only guaranteed to run at 10MHz @ 3.7V.

Answer (score 2):

You can connect it directly, but note that the frequency you run it at is affected by voltage:

0- 4MHz@1.8 - 5.5V

0 - 10MHz@2.7 - 5.5V

0 - 20MHz@ 4.5 - 5.5V

[image]

Comment: In practice though, you *can* clock the newer avr parts at ~16MHz down at 2.7 even though the datasheet says otherwise. I just wouldn't trust it for anything where timing is critical...